# Replace everything between two tags with regex

Tags: python, regex

If I have an xml tag, such as:

```
<tag>
    ... abunch of stuff inside here
</tag>
```

How would I remove everything inside , inclusive of the tags itself?

I tried `re.sub('<tag>.+</tag>', '', string)` but it wasn't working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: first of all you should learn the essence about parsing html by regex [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it safely? with `lxml` which goes against your desire to `re` but you might have been persuaded by other's comments that using `re` is fraught with danger.

```
import lxml.etree as etree

xml = """<root>
<item name="1"/>
<item name="2"/>
<tag>
    <nested>Will I die</nested>
    ... abunch of stuff inside here
</tag>
<another/>
</root>"""

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
for to_kill in root.xpath("//tag"):
    to_kill.getparent().remove(to_kill)

print etree.tostring(root,  pretty_print=True)
```

Gives:

```
<root>
<item name="1"/>
<item name="2"/>
<another/>
</root>
```

Answer (score 5):

You [can't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/721269) parse XML with a regex. It's just not possible. Many have created regexes that seem to work and then they break as soon as they face anything not anticipated. You really need to use an XML parser to do this.

Comment: It's always an issue when people generalise from the particular, as David Schwartz says in his comment. It's OK in general to hack a particular piece of Xml with regexp but don't expect it work in the general case.

Answer (score -2):

i actually worked with xml before, but its a long time ago. i was using svgs and i was dealing with editting svgs. If you want to delete stuff inside of the tags, I believe you should look for your answer in javascript or jquery.